# How to Reshape dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, attributes

I am playing around some machine learning on a dataset. I am pretty new to pandas/numpy in python..so i am not able to figure out the solution.i have a dataframe obtained by read_csv function using pandas. The dataframe is similar as shown below

```
ID   ATTR  QUANTITY
17   203      14
17   201      8
17   111      1
159  80       5
178  82       16
```

and i want this data-frame to be reshaped / flattened like:

```
    ID  | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | totalQuantity..................goes on
===========================================================
    17  |  203  |  201  |  111  |   23 (i.e sum where id == 17)
    159 |  80   |   0   |   0   |   5
    178 |  82   |   0   |   0   |   16
    ....
```

A piece of code highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create column `att` for pivotting by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) Then use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for `df1` and [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) for `df2`. Last [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) `df1` with `df2` and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by `0`:

```
print df
     ID  ATTR  QUANTITY
0    17   203        14
1    17   201         8
2    17   111         1
3    17   203        14
4    17   201         8
5    17   111         1
6    17   203        14
7    17   201         8
8    17   111         1
9    17   203        14
10   17   201         8
11   17   111         1
12  159    80         5
13  178    82        16

#add column att for counting groups items
df['att'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].cumcount() + 1
#pivot df with column att
df1 = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='att', values='ATTR').reset_index()
#add string 'attr' to columns names
df1.columns =  [df1.columns[0]] + ['attr' + str(col) for col in df1.columns[1:]] 
df2 = df.groupby('ID')['QUANTITY'].sum().reset_index()
#merge with sum
print pd.merge(df1, df2 , on=['ID']).fillna(0)
```

```
    ID  attr1  attr2  attr3  attr4  attr5  attr6  attr7  attr8  attr9  attr10  \
0   17    203    201    111    203    201    111    203    201    111     203   
1  159     80      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0   
2  178     82      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0   

   attr11  attr12  QUANTITY  
0     201     111        92  
1       0       0         5  
2       0       0        16
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer.  Seems to work partially though. Its creating columns and filling them with values , but i don't  know why the order of creation of columns is a bit  strange.

Comment: The order followed is
Index([u'id', u'attr1', u'attr10', u'attr11', u'attr12', u'attr13', u'attr14', u'attr15', u'attr16', u'attr17', u'attr18', u'attr19', u'attr2', u'attr20', u'attr3', u'attr4', u'attr5', u'attr6', u'attr7', u'attr8', u'attr9'], dtype='object')

Comment: i have around 50k rows in the dataset and the function takes around 1 minute to execute. BTW, what should i check?? I see the code is same as earlier

Comment: Solution is edited and now is faster. Please check it.

Comment: ThankYou very much. Works like a charm. takes just 3 -4 seconds :)  You are awesome